# How to add post/content reading time in a django blog?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-models, blogs

I am trying to add content read time in django app (**posts**) but its not working properly don't know whats going wrong.

**posts/models.py** :

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils import timezone
from markdown_deux import markdown
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from .utils import get_read_time

#from comments.models import Comment
#from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


#to specify image upload location we define a function

#def upload_location(instance, filename):
   # return "%s/%s" % (instance.pk, filename)

class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostManager,self).filter(draft=False).filter(publish__lte=timezone.now())


class Post(object):
    pass


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,
                              blank=True,)
                              #upload_to=upload_location)

    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    read_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


    objects = PostManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


    # for latest posts on top of page
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp', 'updated']

    def get_markdown(self):
        content = self.content
        markdown_text = markdown(content)
        return mark_safe(markdown_text)

   # @property
    #def comments(self):
    #    instance = self
    #    qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
    #    return qs

   # @property
    #def get_content_type(self):
    #    instance = self
    #    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_models(instance.__class__)
    #    return content_type

    def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        if instance.content:
            html_string = instance.get_markdown()
            read_time_var = get_read_time(html_string)
            instance.read_time = read_time_var

    pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Post)
```

Added a python file in my app as  **utils.py**

**posts/utils.py**

```
import datetime
import re
import math
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

def count_words(html_string):
    word_string = strip_tags(html_string)
    matching_words = re.findall(r'\w+', word_string)
    count = len(matching_words)
    return count

def get_read_time(html_string):
    count = count_words(html_string)
    #read_time_min = (count/200.0)
    read_time_min = math.ceil(count/200.0)
    #read_time_sec = read_time_min * 60
    #read_time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=read_time_sec))
    read_time = str(datetime.timedelta(minutes=read_time_min))
    return int(read_time)
```

code from **posts/posts_detail.html:**

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        {% if instance.image %}
            <img src="{{ instance.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
        {% endif %}
        <h1>{{ title }} <small>
            {% if instance.draft %}
                <span style="color: red"> (Draft) </span>
            {% endif %}
            {{ instance.publish}}</small></h1>
        <p>Read time: {% if instance.read_time <= 1 %} < 1 Minute {% else %}{{ instance.read_time }} minutes {% endif %}</p>
        {% if instance.user.get_full_name %}
            <p>Author : {{ instance.user.get_full_name }}</p>
        {% endif %}
```

I am getting `Read time: 0` in `admin` and `Read time: < 1 Minute` in blog

Don't know where making mistake.

Please Guide.

***Note: Using Django 1.10 and Python 3.4***

Comment: @e4c5 can you please help me out!?

Comment: instance.read_time?? but the function name what you registered is get_read_time. is it not different? and can you post the admin code and th displayed content?

Comment: It would also be agreat idea to escape the html opening tag character.    &#34;  
 &#60;   &#62; to represent "   <   >  ?

Answer (score 5):

There's another way around if you plan to use python readtime library. It is pretty straightforward and easy to integrate.

```
pip install readtime
```

Then you have to import it in models.py file (Here it is Post Model):

```
import readtime
```

Add a function in the model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   content = models.TextField()

   def get_readtime(self):
      result = readtime.of_text(self.content)
      return result.text 

   def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

If your views.py is like this:

```
 def post_detail(request, id):
       post_detail = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
       context = {
          'post_detail':post_detail,
           }
       return render(request, 'post/post_detail.html', context)
```

Then in post detail template use:

```
 {{post_detail.get_readtime}}
```

Answer (score 2):

One other solution that seems to work for me and I highly prefer, is to create a template tag that will determine the read time.

```bash
pip install readtime
```

1. Create a `templatetags`

```
├── __init__.py
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── 0002_alter_article_description_and_more.py
│   ├── 0003_alter_article_description.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── templates
│   ├── _pagination.html
│   ├── _result.html
│   ├── category.html
│   ├── home.html
│   └── view.html
├── templatetags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── read_time.py
│   └── renderjson.py
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

2. create the tag function

```py
from django import template
from readtime import of_html

register = template.Library()


def read(html):
    return of_html(html)


register.filter('readtime', read)
```

3. use it

```html
{% load read_time %}
<a href="/blog/{{blog.slug}}" class="blog">
    <img alt="{{blog.title}}" class="blog-image" src="{{blog.cover_img_url}}">
    <div class="blog-content">
        <div class="d-flex gap-4">
            <h5 class="blog-subtitle text-muted mb-2 mt-3 fs-6">{{blog.updated_at}}</h5>
            <h5 class="text-muted mb-2 mt-3 fs-6">{{ blog.description | readtime }}</h5>
        </div>
        <h5 class="blog-title">{{blog.title}}</h5>
        <p class="blog-preview">
            {{blog.subtitle|truncatechars:250}}
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

**NB:** for this example I have used HTML because of my Django project setup

reference: https://raturi.in/blog/django-calculate-readtime-for-an-article-post-text/

hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
read_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I think you should use `TimeField` instead of `IntegerField`

```
read_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any utils.py, or any external lib

Just a method like `get_read_time()` will do :)

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    # other stuff
    
    def get_read_time(self):
        from html import unescape
        from django.utils.html import strip_tags
        
        string = self.title + unescape(strip_tags(self.content))
        total_words = len((string).split())

        return round(total_words / 200)
```

PS: Note that we've also taken the title into consideration

Then in post detail template:

```
 {{ instance.get_read_time }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a StreamField blog, I used the following adjustments to the solution posted by @vaibhav-shukla.  This provides fine control over which block types are included in the reading time calculation, e.g. not counting raw HTML code blocks which can often be v. long when used for visualizations.

```
    def get_read_time(self):
        string = self.title
        for block in self.body:
            if block.block_type not in ['image', 'html']:
                string += unescape(strip_tags(block))
        total_words = len((string).split())
        return round(total_words / 200)
```